# PHP $GET If Wrong Form No

Tags: php

I have question about PHP $GET. I have an edit link like this :

```
<a href="edit.php?form_no=<?php echo $form_no; ?>"
```

After I clicked, it will redirect to details page that show data based on form no.

```
<?php
$form_no = $_GET['form_no'];
if wrong get form no
{
}
?>
```

Now I facing problem if I type in url web address wrong form no. What I want to do is redirect to another page if user type wrong form no.

Any advice?

Comment: And what is your question? Where are you stuck doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong form no ? Once you retrieve form_no from post, you can use conditions (eg - if ($form_no > 10) {}) to redirect to another page. Redirect can be done with "header('Location: '.$url)"

Comment: What I want to do is redirect to another page if user type wrong form no.

Comment: And you question is *"how to redirect"* or *"how to decide if the form no is wrong"*?!

Comment: `if ($form_no != <YOUR_NUMBER>) header('Location: *where you want your form to go*');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to have a condition that whether that form id exists in the database, if no than redirect so for that

```
//Query

$id_to_edit = $_GET['id']; 
/* Don't forget to sanitize, i.e is your id only numeric, no html in the id etc */

$fetch_ids = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM tbl_name WHERE id = $id_to_edit");

if(mysqli_num_rows($fetch_ids) == 0) { //Check, if no rows are returned so redirect
   header('Location: whatever.php');
   exit;
}
```

You can also throw up an error that Id doesn't exists, by setting a session before redirecting, throw up an error on the redirected page and later unset the session var